# Как убрать костыли из вычисления суммы чисел, введенных в консоли?

Tags: java, строки, консоль, split

Есть задача:
В первой строке ввести n - количество целых чисел. Во второй строке ввести числа через пробел, чисел может быть введено >n. Вывести сумму n первых введенных чисел.
Решение довольно простое:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int amountOfNum = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.skip("\n");
    String numString = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] arrayNum = numString.split(" ");
    int summ = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfNum; i++) {
        summ += Integer.parseInt(arrayNum[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(summ);
}
```

Но по самому решению есть вопросы:

1. Как то же самое сделать без строки `scanner.skip("\n");`? Т.к. это
   очевидный костыль, но без этой строки `scanner.nextLine()` считывает
   предыдущий перенос строки и не дает ввести числа
2. Есть ли еще варианты извлечения из строки чисел без использования
   метода `split`? Только парсить вручную?
3. Для чего это нужно? Исключительно академический интерес.

Comment: Укажите язык программирования.

Comment: на java похоже.

Comment: "для чего это нужно" - "это" - это что именно? Если "зачем всё это делать?", то это нужно спросить у того, кто создал эту задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу пунктов 1 и 2: достаточно использовать `nextInt` вместо `nextLine`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int amountOfNum = scanner.nextInt();
    int summ = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfNum; i++)
    {
        summ += scanner.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(summ);
}
```

По поводу пункта 3: если задача придумана для того, чтобы обучить считыванию чисел с консоли, то нужно это... для обучения считыванию чисел с консоли. На практике такое может потребоваться только в какой-то расчудесной ситуации, при которой нужно посчитать сумму больших чисел, но при этом вы не можете воспользоваться калькулятором, зато у вас есть эта программа и возможность её запустить.

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался

Comment: @kernel40 на здоровье. Если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте отметить его как принятый.